I'm having a problem with stamina mechanics
if keys_pressed.get(K_SPACE) and stamina > 0:
    speed += 150
    for i in range(stamina):
        stamina -= 1
    if stamina == 0:
        speed -= 150
        for i in range(stamina):
            stamina += 1

I wanted it so when the player sprinted they would drain their stamina, the idea was, the longer the held down the spacebar (the sprint button in this case), they would see their stamina decrease, and when it reached 0 they'd be restricted to their normal speed before they had any stamina to sprint again.
However, it didn't work, the for loops only take 50 away straight away from the stamina variable, when I release the spacebar it adds fifty straight back on the player still sprints fine, it's the stamina mechanic I'm having trouble with, because not only am I experiencing the said logic error, it's also not removing the extra speed gained when stamina is zero.

In general you would only stamina -= 1 once per "tick" (or whatever time interval), which would depend on what you are using for your game engine.

There is nothing in the loop that tells python to slow the execution down, or interleave it with some other process (your character moving), so the loop is just executed all at once. We will need to see your other code in order to suggest any solution.

The for loop will be executed for the whole amount of stamina before the loop is exited. So you could bring the stamina check inside of the loop and add an exit statement, which would stop sprinting, as soon as no stamina was left. Your code also has the issue that stamina is regenerated while the spacebar is still pushed (unless you want that behaviour).
But in general, if you use pygame as your engine, like CoryKramer and tobias_k said, you need to correctly use the game loop (pygame has the clock function for that), and only do the stamina reduction once.
